# Play framework 2.0 sample app doesn't change when I edit source

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm playing with play framework 2.0. I've copied the 'computer-database' application, run it with 'play run' and viewed it in my browser at http://localhost:9000. I run the evolution and browse the app. But when I edit a template and hit reload, nothing changes. Even stopping play and starting it again makes no difference.

What am I doing wrong? I thought the whole point was that I could edit, refresh and see my changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same issue here, what I typically do is Hit CTRL+D in the SBT console and issue a`compile` command, followed by a `run`

Note that dynamic compilation works fine when you change code.

This is probably a bug.

Comment: i still can't get it to work doing a compile. I haven't found anywhere on github to post issues, so I guess we'll have to hope they spot it.

Comment: it has been raised a number of times on the google groups, so the issue has been raised with the development team, and they are aware.